# Recaptcha (both v2 and v3) not working on Samsung Browser (but works with HTTPS)

Tags: javascript, android, html, recaptcha, samsung-mobile

I am having a very strange problem with Google Recaptcha and it has started since mid October. I can confirm that this is happening for both Recaptcha v2 and newer v3. Its primarily happening on mobile Samsung Browser, but working fine on chrome, safari, firefox on mobile.

This is the frontend code, I am using for v2

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE_KEY"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue">
    </form>
</body>
```

I am not posting the server side validation since the problem is occurring even before that. In Samsung Mobile Browser, as soon as the page loads with this code, i can see the recaptcha checkbox loading fine, but when I try to tick/check the checkbox, It doesn't work. The loading blue circle keeps spinning and nothing happens thereafter. The same thing works fine on mobile chrome, safari and firefox, and it indeed turns into a green checkmark.

I was experimenting with this, when I found that when I use https with the domain name instead of http (even though I dont have an SSL certificate or real HTTPS) but it does the trick..opening the page with https resolve this issue in Samsung mobile browser. While in chrome and other browsers, it works fine without HTTPS as well.

The same issue happens with newer recaptcha v3 as well..in that case it doesn't generate token but on using HTTPS, it does work fine.

for some reason, I cannot get or use HTTPS on my current page. I am looking for a solution which might do the trick so the recaptcha starts working on Samsung Mobile Browser as well.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem recently with my applications: Recaptcha doesn't work in HTTP mode but in HTTPS it works correctly and happens with native browsers such as Samsung Internet and the Browser app on Huawei mobiles. Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Ecosia etc work correctly. I'm curious to find a solution for HTTP as well since not all sites need HTTPS.